# Null Replacement in Oracle Pivot Table

Tags: oracle, pivot, case-when

I am currently using the following code to pivot a table and it works perfectly.   Now I want to replace any null values with 'No Data' after it is summed but I am getting errors, so I think I am placing the case statement in the wrong place.

This works:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT PROV_NO, DATA_YEAR, DATA_MONTH, MEASURE_ID, CASES
    FROM   pivot_test_2)
PIVOT  (SUM(CASES) FOR (MEASURE_ID) IN ('MORT_30_AMI', 'MORT_30_HF', 'MORT_30_PN'))
order by PROV_NO, DATA_YEAR, DATA_MONTH;
```

but this does not

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT PROV_NO, DATA_YEAR, DATA_MONTH, MEASURE_ID, CASES
    FROM   pivot_test_2)
PIVOT  (SUM(CASES) FOR (MEASURE_ID) IN ('MORT_30_AMI', 'MORT_30_HF', 'MORT_30_PN'))
case when MORT_30_HF is null then 'No Data' else MORT_30_HF end
order by PROV_NO, DATA_YEAR, DATA_MONTH;
```

I get "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" as the error.  I'm trying to place ";" around but the error is still the same.   I am currently in Oracle 11g and using Golden as my scripting/retrieval software.

Comment: Are you sure you want to show 'No Data' in a column that should otherwise be numeric? If you use the output for further processing this will be a pain; and if all you need this for is reporting, while you can do it in SQL, this is a job best done by your reporting system/software/application.

Comment: That's a good point, but yes I do, this is the final output and no further processing is done on it.  This is for an outwards facing report so the No Data string looks better than blanks.

Comment: Understood, but you can replace NULLs with 'No Data' in your reporting system. If you have strings in the results from your query, your interface will likely align the columns to the left instead of to the right (as is usual for numbers) - that may also not look good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the CASE statement to the SELECT statement and handle the NULL values there. Better yet, use COALESCE.  But unfortunately you have to do this for each item in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT
       --Must manually reference each column.
       COALESCE(TO_CHAR(MORT_30_AMI), 'No Data') MORT_30_AMI,
       COALESCE(TO_CHAR(MORT_30_HF), 'No Data') MORT_30_HF,
       COALESCE(TO_CHAR(MORT_30_PN), 'No Data') MORT_30_PN,
       PROV_NO, DATA_YEAR, DATA_MONTH
FROM   (SELECT PROV_NO, DATA_YEAR, DATA_MONTH, MEASURE_ID, CASES
        FROM   pivot_test_2)
PIVOT 
       (
          SUM(CASES)
          FOR (MEASURE_ID) IN
          --Use aliases to make the columns easier to use.
          ('MORT_30_AMI' MORT_30_AMI, 'MORT_30_HF' MORT_30_HF, 'MORT_30_PN' MORT_30_PN))
ORDER BY PROV_NO, DATA_YEAR, DATA_MONTH;
```

**A Simpler Version That Doesn't Work**

Ideally you would be able to replace this part of the code:

```
SUM(CASES)
```

With this:

```
COALESCE(TO_CHAR(SUM(CASES)), 'No data')
```

Then you wouldn't need to handle each column separately.  But there doesn't appear to be a way to automatically apply a non-aggregate function to the results of a PIVOT.  Using the above code generates this error message:

> ORA-56902: expect aggregate function inside pivot operation

**Sample Schema**

```
create table pivot_test_2
(
  PROV_NO CHAR(6),
  DATA_YEAR NUMBER(4),
  DATA_MONTH Number(2),
  MEASURE_ID VARCHAR2(250),
  CASES NUMBER
);

insert into pivot_test_2
select 'A', 2000, 1, 'MORT_30_AMI', 1 from dual union all
select 'A', 2000, 1, 'MORT_30_AMI', 1 from dual union all
select 'A', 2000, 1, 'MORT_30_HF',  2 from dual union all
select 'A', 2000, 1, 'MORT_30_HF',  2 from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know about Coalesce, however I now get this error: ORA-00904: "CASES": invalid identifier  from the "PROV_NO, DATA_YEAR, DATA_MONTH, MEASURE_ID, CASES
" line

Comment: To suggest the obvious, can you remove `CASES` from the select list, or is that column an absolute requirement for you?

Comment: If remove that one, it still get the same error on the Pivot statement.  Its not liking Cases now.  Its what I sum on, so its necessary.  I'll just keep banging away at it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Darw1n34 Can you post the table structure for `pivot_test_2` in your question?  I don't see anything wrong my query at first glance.

Comment: PROV_NO - CHAR(6), DATA_YEAR - NUMBER (4), DATA_MONTH - Number (2), MEASURE_ID - VARCHAR2(250), CASES - NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, with help from you all, I was able to cob this together and it works.

```
SELECT PROV_NO, DATA_YEAR, DATA_MONTH,
case when MORT_30_AMI is null then 'No Data' else to_char(MORT_30_AMI) end as MORT_30_AMI,
case when MORT_30_HF is null then 'No Data' else to_char(MORT_30_HF) end as MORT_30_HF,
case when MORT_30_PN is null then 'No Data' else to_char(MORT_30_PN) end as MORT_30_PN
    FROM  pivot_test_2
PIVOT  (SUM(CASES) FOR (MEASURE_ID) IN ('MORT_30_AMI' as MORT_30_AMI,'MORT_30_HF' as MORT_30_HF, 'MORT_30_PN' as MORT_30_PN))
order by PROV_NO, DATA_YEAR, DATA_MONTH;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DECODE keyword for the query defined fields (from the list of pivot defined fields) and then replace NULL with whatever value you need. i.e., instead of NULL replace it with 'No Data'. I believe that should solve this issue.